# Updating resources in RESTful API with forms or representations

Tags: json, rest, xhtml

I saw many examples where XHTML  were used in RESTful API for authorization with OAuth or OpenID. While this seems quite natural I asked myself **if there are other advantages where submitting forms is better then POSTing/PUTing a representation of the resource** ? I'm mostly interested in machine-to-machune interaction then human-to-machine.

If I understand it well, one of the aspects is the content-negotiation where XHTML forms can be returned to the client or not (because by default JSON and XML doesn't support forms) depending on the `Accept` header in the request.

Let's say we have a simple scenario where an `Item` resource could be added to the `Cart` resource. The API supports only JSON and XML. What I'm generally doing is I want the client to `POST` an `Item` resource representation to the `Cart` resource and this works great. However the client should be aware of the semantics and need to know exactly the structure of the `Item` resource representation because otherwise it will encounter error 400 (Bad request).

Then I thought then using forms would be easier **as they provide some guidance** to the client on what to post to the `Cart`. But then there is a problem, because  are supported OOTB by XHTML for example but not JSON or XML (unless using something like Collection-JSON etc.). I could then provide some custom implementation in order to support forms in JSON and XML but this would require client to understand the semantics and there is **no gain in using forms over posting the resource representation**.

**Question :**
Could you please clarify if there are scenarios where forms should be used, or the usage is preferable over POSTing a resource representation ? Is there any official guidance ?

**Question 2 :**
Would you bother using forms in XHTML format where mostly all communication between API and clients is in JSON or XML, or would you modify XML/JSON in order to contain custom forms ?

Maybe I'm missing something about that, so don't hesitate to put me on the right tracks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add an item to a cart, there are 2 options.

1.
The cart is part of the REST client's state, so you do not store that information in the REST service. In that case you can store items and amounts on the client side or in cookie, or in a server side REST client, it does not really matter. You should store the url of the items, the id of the items, and the amount, and maybe the price too... All of these come from the REST service...

2.
The cart is stored in the REST service, so it is a resource, and any change of that has an effect on the resource states of the service. In this case you can create a cart with a `POST /carts` request, after that you will get a unique cart id:

```
201
{
    id: 123,
    _links: {
        self: {href: "/carts/123"}
    }
}
```

your client has to remember that, so if you get a link template by the catalog, for example `/items?search=@keywords&cart=@cart.id`, you can fill the cart id on that...

By browsing the catalog you can get the items this way: `GET /items?search="red pullover"&cart=123`. After that you will get an `add-cart` link by any item:

```
{
    id: 567,
    name: "red pullover",
    _links: {
        "add-cart": {
            href: "/cart-items",
            fields: {
                cart: {type: "hidden", value: 123},
                item: {type: "hidden", value: 567},
                amount: {type: "select", value: 1, min: 1, max: 10}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can create a form and a button from that link if the `session.cart.id` exists in the client. If not then you can ignore that link. If you are pressing the button in the generated form, it will send something like this to the service:

```
POST /cart-items
{
    cart: 123,
    item: 567,
    amount: 1
}

201
{
    id: 22222,
    _links: {
        self: {href: "/cart-items/22222"}
    }
}
```

So if you want your service stay RESTful, your client must never generate links. It gets links always from the service. The service never stores client state, the client state always comes in queryString or postData...

You can send the response in HTML to your REST client, and the REST client decides what to do with the response, and how to display it. It is better to send the responses in a data format, for example HAL+JSON or JSON-LD or ATOM+XML, because they have already existing serializers and unserializers. HTML does not have a serializer/unserializer, just a slow parser, so if you use HTML you have to write that part of the code by yourself.

You can find out your own form representation for example with HAL+JSON, or your can use already existing schemas. JSON-LD and ATOM+XML and HAL+HTML can be bound to existing RDF schemas or maybe to microformats, so maybe there is a schema about how to describe forms. You can browse already existing schemas for example on [schema.org](http://schema.org/), or you can find already existing link relations here: [link-relations](http://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml). There are many other solutions about almost everything, not just about displaying forms, but about representing data. Your can find out more with the keywords: linked data, linked open data, etc...

Comment: Nice explanation. The fields you've used in the cart link are a kind of standard you've mentioned, or something that you have made by yourself and that you have to communicate to all clients how to parse this information ?

Comment: This is my implementation. HAL+JSON just defines how to send links, I don't think it has form descriptions yet, but I am sure there is a microdata which describes that kind of information in a standard way. I just did not have the time to browse microdata catalog yet...